# How to modify other account's startup files to start with an initial configuration in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, startup, administrator

I have two accounts:

1. user (normal account) and
2. _user (administrator account).
   I cannot log in with the `user` account as it is corrupted but I can do with `_user` account. So, as a possible solution, I want to login with `_user` account and **set `user` account's startup files to start with an initial configuration** (i.e. to make `user` starts with `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.inputrc`, and `.profile`).

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all files that you mentioned from `/home/user`.
Copy all the files from `/etc/skel` to `/home/user` (remeber to change their owner to `user`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The `/etc/skel` is empty.

Comment: There should be hidden files `.profile`, `.bashrc` and similar in `/etc/skel`. You need to copy them to `/home/user`. Check with `ls -la /etc/skel`.

Comment: Ah! I found `.bash_logout`, `.bashrc`, and `.profile`. I will come back after trying your suggestion.

Comment: It works! Although I don't know whether this suggestion modified the startup files of the `user`, it solved my problem, anyway. Thank you!

Comment: You replaced the startup files in `/home/user` directory with the default startup files used when any new account is created (that's what `/etc/skel` directory is for), so that's what you asked for in your question.

Comment: Cool! Thank you for your additional explanation :)